# Sending ePubs from PC to iOS iBooks via iCloud Drive?

Tags: icloud, windows, books

So my goal is to use iCloud Drive to hold all of my ebooks and organize accordingly. On my iPad and iPhone, I have enabled iCloud Drive and by iBooks in Manage iCloud Drive, toggled that on too.

From the PC, using the iCloud for Windows iCloud Drive interface (which essentially looks like Windows Explorer), I dump all of the ePubs into a folder named eBooks (that’s what I named it, but would not be opposed to any other name, really). The ePub files don’t show up in iBooks. If I navigate to settings and iCloud Drive, I can navigate into the ebooks folder and see them that way. Is there something I’m missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iCloud Drive and iBooks aren't directly linked, so you have to open Files app on your iOS device (iOS 11+) and open it in iBooks. The iBooks iCloud setting specifically refers to keeping iOS and Mac iBooks apps in sync with each other.

iBooks has a setting at the top that says "All Books" with a down triangle on it or something similar. Tap that and at the bottom of the screen, there is a toggle that says "Hide iCloud Books". Toggle that off and tap done.

Now, navigate in Files app on iOS and find the non-protected .epub you want to move to iBooks and tap it. It should download and open in iBooks.

Do note that since they aren't linked, deleting files in iBooks and deleting files in iCloud Drive should affect each other.

Comment: I have a feeling you might be right that it is the only method. It is a shame it can't pull in automatically, but I can live with this. Thanks.